# Symfony 3.3 - Unable to select empty value using EntityType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a following problem. I have a country form where I use the *EntityType* to select a contact person from a list of *User* entities. Symfony correctly renders select with an empty option. Contact person is not required, so the empty option can be selected. So if I select the empty option, I want empty string (sent in request) to be transformed to *null*. According to the [EntityType Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-data) It can be done when `'empty_data' => null` is set. This works for *create form*. But If I have already set a contact person in *create form* and I want to set contact person to *null* in *edit form* , *null* is ignored and value is not changed. Change from user A to user B works fine. Does anybody know why it does not change?

Part of the *buildForm* method from *CountryType.php*:

```
$builder->add('contactPerson', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'choice_label' => 'username',
    'empty_data' => null,
    'required' => false,
    // 'placeholder' => '' - Can be ommited, empty value is default
]);
```

Part of the *Country.orm.yml*:

```
 manyToOne:       
    contactPerson:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\User
        joinColumn:
            name: contact_person
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: RESTRICT
            nullable: true
        fetch: EAGER
```

*editAction* method of *CountryController.php*:

```
    public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        /** @var CountryService $countryService */
        $countryService = $this->get('app.country');
        /** @var Country $country */
        $country = $countryService->findById($id);

        if (!$country) {
            $this->addFlash('error', 'back.country.not_found');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('back_country_list');
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(
            CountryType::class,
            $country,
            [
                'edit_action' => true
            ]
        );
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $countryService->edit($country);

            $this->addFlash('success', 'back.country.edited');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('back_country_edit', ['id' => $id]);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:back\country:edit.html.twig',
            [
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]
        );
    }
```

Content of POST request looks like:

```
"contactPerson" => ""
```

But If I enter `die(dump($country->getContactPerson())` somewhere after `$form->handleRequest($request)`, value is still set to *User*, not to *null*.

Thank you for help!

Comment: What is the logic change in your type with this option `'edit_action' => true` ?

Comment: It just change a label of a submit button between Add and Edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been big suprise to me but I have probably found a bug in the Symfony. See bug report for more info: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25181

Comment: what a pain to fix it, both issues are https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25181 and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23961 are closed and apparently related to doctrine.

Answer (score 4):

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
```

use above class and try the following code

```
$builder->add('contactPerson', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'choice_label' => 'username',
    'required' => false,
    'placeholder' => 'Please choose a contact person',
    'empty_data' => null,
]);
```

Comment: Thank youf for response. It is not visible in the snippet above but I already use `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;` in my code. `placeholder => ' ... '` only sets a text which is being displayed in the select but I does not affect anything else :/

Comment: perfect solution, thanks